# Google Visualization - Chart Wrapper with Diff Chart w/ Stacked Column Charts

Tags: google-visualization

I am developing a dashboard that has a bunch of charts and pulls data from a Google spreadsheet.  I would like one chart to be a Diff chart with stacked column graphs.  Essentially, there would be a stacked column graph in front and another behind.  This is the same concept as the Diff chart with column graphs, but I would like to have stacked column graphs displayed.  For the dashboards, the charts must be in in a Chart Wrapper, but I cannot think about how to do this.

Is this possible?  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the Diff Chart to work in Chart Wrapper, but the solution that I developed consists of having the front graph with a 'transparent' fill and narrow bars.  Then a similar-sized stacked column chart can be positioned underneath this div (with a smaller z-index).  Same effect that I was trying to have...